# Reset form validation after successful ajax submit asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

**Technologies:**

Asp.net MVC
jQuery/Validation

**Setup:**

I have a view, loaded via `ajax`, that consists of a create form and list view.

The create form submits the model via `ajax`.  I have a js/jQuery function that performs this action on submit:

```
$("#content").on("submit", ".create-form", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
    $(this).validate();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        //alert($(this).serialize());
        var action = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something went wrong");
            }

        })
    }
})
```

My model has several typical validation attributes and one Remote validation attribute:

```
[Required]
[Remote("AssetTagExists","Inventory")]
[Display(Name = "Asset Tag")]
public int AssetId { get; set; }
```

**The Problem:**

All validation works perfectly the first time I submit the form.  However, since I'm not refreshing the page after the `ajax` call (the entire reason I'm using `ajax` in the first place), the validation does not reset.  The simple `[Required]` fields still detect and alert the user if a field is blank but the behavior is slightly different.  It no longer waits until the submit button is pressed to validate.  The remote validation field does not validate at all anymore.

The only option I have so far is just reloading the create form with another ajax call after a successful submit, but this is not ideal.  Am I missing something simple here to reset the validation?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the form `form.reset()`?

Comment: ^^ On your success callback

Comment: Holy crap...Thank you very much.  I can't believe it was that simple...

Comment: You cannot call `.validate()` within a submit handler because this is what initializes the plugin on your form.  However, it's a moot point when you're using the Unobtrusive plugin, since this already calls `.validate()` for you.   You also cannot call `.validate()` more than once.   Your instance of `.validate()` is superfluous and will be ignored.

Comment: Ah I see.  I had grabbed that from a previous project in which my items weren't validating if they were loaded in via ajax.  I guess I had assumed that it wouldn't work.  I have tried it in this instance and it works without that call too.  Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: It's critical to call `form.reset()` and `validator.resetForm()` in an ajax callback. Calling them directly in the submit handler (like I did during development because I hadn't written the controller for my ajax call yet) does not work. The validator will not reset properly and will immediately validate the now-empty form.